# Creating python code for spring mass forces

Tags: python, algorithm, physics

I'm trying to create a function that will calculate the sum of the forces F1+F2+Gravity. According to my calculations, the formula I am trying to create is
[image: Here]

So far I've done the basics -

```
import numpy

#varibles from example problem
a1 = numpy.array([0,0])
a2 = numpy.array([1,1])
s1,s2 = 10,10 
L1,L2=1,2
m=1
def SpringForces(a1,a2,s1,s2,l,m):
    G = numpy.array([0,-9.81*m]) 
    #algorithm
    return F1+F2+G
```

I'm really not sure where to begin creating the formula. Should I create a small for loop for k equal to 1 and 2?

EDIT:
new code I have is

```
  def SpringForces(a1,a2,s1,s2,L1,L2,m):
    G = numpy.array([0,-9.81*m]) 
    F1 = s1 * ((L1)/numpy.abs(x-a1)-1) * (x-a1)
    F2 = s2 * ((L2)/numpy.abs(x-a2)-1) * (x-a2)
    return F1+F2+G
```

Comment: Please use code which actually works in your comment, so far you have an unindented block after a function definition and double = signs in your G declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define your SpringForce function to calculate each spring force seperately, then add the forces together at the end.

```
def springForce(x, s, a, l):
    return s*((l/abs(x-a))-1)*(x-a)

F = springForce(x, s1, a1, l1) + springForce(x, s2, a2, l2) + G
```

It's worth noting that what you did with your function in your initial code example is a little pointless.   There are two reasons you might want to make a function:

1. To avoid repeating exactly the same code multiple times
2. To abstract away chunks of code, potentially enhancing readability

Your function as written doesn't do either of these two things, so you would be better off without it.

Comment: agree about `springForce` signature and approach. +1

Answer (score 0):

At this point, you should *not* use a loop, because you don't have any structures through which you can iterate comfortably.  If you turn your subscripted elements (e.g. `s1, s2`) into arrays or lists rather than appended variable names, *then* you have leverage for a loop.  For merely two elements, though, I'd suggest that you write each equation separately.  Generalize when you're more comfortable with the constructs.